# HMAC-based cookies weaknesses

Tags: cookies, hmac

I am currently studying stateless servers design.
I learnt how to store HMAC-based token in HTTP cookies.
The idea is that the server has a secret key and is the only entity able to generate valid tokens.

I also read this thread:
[How do stateless servers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495950/how-do-stateless-servers-work)

There is an interesting example about Paypal-like website.
If an attacker just copy the content of a token, he can do whatever he want with the account until the token being invalid.

I see several ways to avoid that issue:

- Store IP address or its hash in the token: possibly annoying for user?
- Store user-agent or its hash in the token: low added value
- Ask for re-authentication for security-based use cases (ex: password change)
- Add a one-time password layer

Is there additional weaknesses?
How to protect against these weaknesses?